# Comparison between Amazon web services (AWS) or Rackspace cloud servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rackspace-cloud

There are two major offering of cloud computing environment by Amazon through AWS and by Rackspace through Rackspace cloud. I wanted to know more about What are cons/pros of one platform over other. That will help me in deciding platform for my future applications.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please see some of these links to better analyze & understand the difference between Amazon Cloud Server with Rackspace Cloud.

Things come into my mind:

1. Amazon server stack has CHOICES possibly everything, but Rackspace server stack is fixed.
2. Control everything on your server stack with Amazon but Rackspace - NOPE.
3. You can play around with various services (EBS, EIP, S3, etc) in Amazon server to suite your price, you can't with Rackspace, since you are priced for the whole stack.
4. In Amazon - single EBS AMI, you can have many different instance types of machine.

Difference:

http://www.distractable.net/tech/amazon-aws-ec2-vs-rackspace-high-level-comparison/

Goodby Rackspace:

http://code.mixpanel.com/amazon-vs-rackspace/

Performance Analysis:

http://www.thebitsource.com/featured-posts/rackspace-cloud-servers-versus-amazon-ec2-performance-analysis/